# Is chelev nullified in 1/60?

Tags: bitul-batel-null, chelev

[Vayikra 7:25](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9754&st=&pgnum=78) says that anyone who eats *chelev* (suet) gets *karet*.

Is there a concept of *batel beshishim* (nullification in 1/60) for chelev? Is one liable for *karet* if he ate a food mixture containing < 1/60 chelev? Is there some other punishment?

Comment: Check Chullin 98,intresting daf about diff shiurim of being mevatel issur

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, nullification in 60 applies to suet just like most prohibited foods. ([Rambam, Forbidden Foods 15:17](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968271/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-15.htm))